# Login from the command line

Tags: linux-mint, login, login-screen, udev

OS: Linux, Mint.

I want to have a system where I can insert a flashdrive into a computer, and using the Udev rules, have the system log in a user account. I can do the Udev part, but what command should I run to log in? Google has not helped, nor has poking around the computer.

Comment: I think you could get better answers if you post this on the [UNIX & Linux site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Asked there at your suggestion a few seconds ago.